# Making the UIImagePickerController the default window

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I am making an app in Xcode and I would like to make it open with the camera like in the built in app. I made it in the app delegate and set the window as the UIImagePicker but it did not work. Here is my code:

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    _picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    _picker.delegate = self;
    [_picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    self.window = _picker;
    return YES;
}
```

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you see a warning on the line `self.window = _picker;`?

Comment: Yes it says: Assigning to 'id<UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>' from incompatible type 'AppDelegate *const __strong'

Comment: No, that's on the line `_picker.delegate = self;`.

Comment: Oh oops sorry it says: Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'UIWindow *' from 'UIImagePickerController *'

Comment: I don't understand why self.window = _picker doesn't give you an error, since _picker is not a UIWindow or a subclass. Instead, you should use self.window.rootViewController = _picker;